# data.table execute function on groups of columns

Tags: r, data.table

If I have the following data table

```
m = matrix(1:12, ncol=4)
colnames(m) = c('A1','A2','B1','B2')
d = data.table(m)
```

is it possible to execute a function on sets of columns?

For example the following would be the sum of A1,A2 and B1,B2.

```
   A  B
1: 5 17
2: 7 19
3: 9 21
```

The solution would preferably work with a 500k x 100 matrix

Comment: That storage format is not very good for working with data in R, in my opinion. Better to go to long format: `melt(d, meas=patterns("A","B"), value.name=c("A","B"))` From there, how to sum should be obvious if you've gone through the data.table package vignettes.

Comment: The problem is that if i have 100 columns, each with 500k rows, it becomes quite tedious to melt it.

Comment: Well, things will be even more tedious if you don't melt it, I suspect. If you really need to do a lot of across-columns stuff, maybe you ought to stick to a matrix or array (see `?array` for what that means in R), where you can use `rowSums` and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

A trick would be to `split` the column into groups.

Then you can use `rowSums` as Frank suggests (see comments on question):

```
# using your data example
m <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 4)
colnames(m) <- c('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2')
d <- data.table(m)

# 1) group columns
groups <- split(colnames(d), substr(colnames(d), 1, 1))

# 2) group wise row sums
d[,lapply(groups, function(i) {rowSums(d[, i, with = FALSE])})]
```

**Result**

This will return the `data.table`:

```
   A  B
1: 5 17
2: 7 19
3: 9 21
```

**Explanation**

- `split` creates a list of column names for each group, defined by a (something coercable to a) factor.
- `substr(colnames(m), 1, 1)` takes the first letter as group id, use a different approach (e.g. `sub("([A-Z]).*", "\\1", colnames(m))` for variable number of letters).
- `lapply` is commonly used to apply functions over multiple columns in a `data.table`. Here we create a list output, named as the `groups`, containing the `rowSums`. `with = FALSE` is important to use the value of `i` to get the respective columns from `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely *possible*...

```
d[, ":=" (A = A1 + A2, B = B1 + B2)]
d
   A1 A2 B1 B2 A  B
1:  1  4  7 10 5 17
2:  2  5  8 11 7 19
3:  3  6  9 12 9 21

# Want to drop the old columns?
set(d, j = which(names(d) %in% c("A1", "B1", "A2", "B2")), value = NULL)
d
   A  B
1: 5 17
2: 7 19
3: 9 21
```

Whether it is desirable I shall not tell. Probably better to follow Frank's advice (see comments).

Comment: `d[, .(A = A1 + A2, B = B1 + B2)]`

Comment: I guess the point was the there are 100 columns, and therefore typing in all the combinations is not an option